# How to Get Count of Nested Nodes of a Parent Node in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application that stores **user.getEmail** in the database each time the users **SignUp** using **Google Email Provider** and the user is Pushed to firebase Database under its unique Firebase Random ID generated.
How do I get count of all these basically **Random IDs** under the node **Authenticated-Users** ?
[image]

As you see in the image, I have 2 basically users, I want to get count of these generated IDs for example **2**.

**UPDATED** if this is not possible,Then how to know when All the data is **fully loaded** ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child("Authenticated-Users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        Log.d("TAG", count + "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Or iterating through the childrens like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child("Authenticated-Users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int count = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        Log.d("TAG", count + "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: This works fine according to first part of the question, The **Updated** part of question is remaining ?

Comment: Could you tell me how to know when all the data is **fully loaded** ?

Comment: There is no way in which you can know when the data is fully loaded. Firebase is a Realtime database, so any time changes can take place. So the data might never be complete.

Comment: Thank you sir, I wanna ask you one more question : 
how can I make sure the emailIds under **Authenticated-Users** node are unique ?

Comment: You're welcome! If you want that, change you database structure and instead of using those pusehed ids, use the email address. Then, attach a listener on `Authenticated-Users` node and use `exists()` method on the `DatabaseReference` object. That's it. Cheers!

Comment: Oh Great!
you mean instead of dbRef.push().setValues(..) , I should use **dbRef.push(email).setValue()** ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But don't forget to replace `.` with `,` because Firebase does not allow `.` symbol in name of the key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164625/discussion-between-niamatullah-bakhshi-and-alex-mamo).

Answer (score 0):

you can get child for a given path|location as like:

```
dBPathRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.i(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()+"Count");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```